# How to use `onmouse` through` DOM` in a `div` that contains other TAGS?

Tags: javascript, dom

I need everything inside `idDiv` to return the message`Enter!`When the mouse pointer overlaps this`idDiv` and also return the message `Out!` Whenever the mouse pointer leaves `idDiv`. This is not happening! The error is in the message `Out!` Which is displayed even though the mouse pointer is inside the `idDiv`.

```js
var array1 = ['aaaaa', 'bbbbb', 'ccccc'];

for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
  obj = document.createElement('div');
  obj.setAttribute('id', 'line' + (array1.length - i));
  obj.setAttribute('class', 'class1');
  obj.setAttribute('onmousedown', 'fDown(' + (array1.length - i) + ')');
  obj.setAttribute('onmouseenter', 'fEnter(' + (array1.length - i) + ')');
  obj.setAttribute('onmouseout', 'fOut(' + (array1.length - i) + ')');
  document.getElementById("idDiv").appendChild(obj);

  var nodeNumber = document.createTextNode((i + 1) + 'ª) ');
  var strong = document.createElement('strong');
  strong.appendChild(nodeNumber);
  document.getElementById('line' + (array1.length - i)).appendChild(strong);

  var nodeTxt = document.createTextNode(array1[i]);
  document.getElementById('line' + (array1.length - i)).appendChild(nodeTxt);
}

function fEnter() {
  document.getElementById("p").innerHTML += "Enter! ";
}

function fDown() {
  document.getElementById("p").innerHTML += "Down! ";
}

function fOut() {
  document.getElementById("p").innerHTML += "Out! ";
}
```

```css
.class1 {
  background-color: skyblue;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="idDiv"></div>
Logs:
<p id="p"></p>
```

Comment: using setAttribute is a bad way to add event handlers

Comment: Is there any alternative?